# Simulate random vector conditionally on a subdomain

Tags: conditional-statements, subdomain, simulation, probability

Suppose i have a bivariate random vector which i can simulate from, taking values in a given domain, and for the sake of simplicity let's suppose that it takes values in whole $R^2$.

Suppose now that the density of my random vector in a given subdomain (e.g [0,1]^2) is very small.

To simulate the random values conditionally on being in this given subdomain, the easy technique "simulate unconditionally and discard if it's not in the subdomain" wont be very efficient.

Is there a generic way to simulate conditionally on being in a sub-domain that would be more efficient that this easy trick ?

I have access to a random number generator from my bivariate law, but i don't have access to the law itself (no expression of density, cdf or whatever).

Maybe it's not the right place to post this ?

Comment: If you only can simulate from R^2 and don't have any extra information, I don't see what else you can do other than simulating and discarding. It would seem that if we draw, say, (15.2, 32.3), then you'd like to map it into [0,1]^2, but there is no way to do that without extra assumptions/information. So, other than the random number generator, is there anything else we can use?

Comment: Take a look at rejection methods. In that approach, you sample from a distribution, say q, which is easy to sample over the subdomain, then you keep or reject the sample x according to the ratio of p(x)/q(x) where p is the distribution you really want. If I remember correctly the only requirement is that p(x) < q(x) everywhere in the subdomain.

Comment: @RobertDodier, the OP doesn't seem to know p.

Comment: @JuliusVainora yes, you're right, my mistake.

Comment: Yeah, i dont. I think that my only option is to simulate and reject if not in the domain. Thanks anyway

Comment: I would use importance sampling.